# Does Sass replace Css?

Tags: css, sass

Currently following a sass guide but, in the guide, it auto translates the code into a CSS file. Does this do this by itself or do you have to do it manually? Or (even better) can you just use sass (scss) instead of css files?

Comment: Please write out "irl". Even I don't know what that means.

Comment: You can easily do it manually, or go with something like gulp that automatically processes it into CSS whenever you make a change...or  an integrated development environment (editor) often will do this behind the scenes

Answer (score 2):

Sass is interpreted into CSS. There are several implementations of the interpreter, the "official" one being in Ruby. But until browsers start to naitively support Sass, we're stuck with CSS "under the hood".

Comment: Browsers will never, ever, support SASS natively and using CSS directly I hope will never go away.

Answer (score 2):

From [the Sass documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html):

> Sass is an extension of CSS that adds power and elegance to the basic language. It allows you to use variables, nested rules, mixins, inline imports, and more, all with a fully CSS-compatible syntax.

I am using it a lot because it allows me to write modular, reusable code. Especially variables and mixins are things that I appreciate.

Just like Coffeescript and Typescript are sitting on top of javascript, Sass is sitting on top of CSS.
And you need a preprocessing engine before the browser is able to use it.

So, to answer your question:

Yes, you can use Sass instead of CSS, provided that you run it through the Sass compiler before using it in the browser.

You can run the compiler manually, or set it up so that it watches for changes and auto-compiles it when needed.

Comment: I question the quote that "Sass is an extension of CSS". It is not. Sass **extends** CSS but is not an extension of it since only the W3C can do that. Not being pedantic. Just want to make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

> SASS won't ever replace CSS. CSS is the standard developed by the W3C,
>   and the one browser makers follow (and sometimes advance) when
>   building their browsers' rendering engines. However, SASS and other
>   CSS pre-compilers like LESS and Stylus are making an impact on how
>   people view the evolution of CSS.

[source](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/will-sass-replace-css-in-a-few-years)